# vue загрузка из template по нажатию

Tags: vue.js

Доброго времени суток есть скрипт на vue который должен в компонент загружать содержимое из **template**  по нажатию на одну из кнопок, ошибок никаких нет, но и по нажатию на кнопки так же никакой реакции нет

```
<body>

    <div id="app">

      <div> 
        <div class="container-fluid navbar-inverse bg-inverse"> 
          <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col"> 
              <nav class="navbar"> 
                <form class="form-inline d-flex justify-content-end"> 
                  <div> 
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success mr-3" type="button" @click="switchSign('signin')">Войти</button>
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button" @click="switchSign('signup')">Регистрация</button> 
                    </div> 
                  </form> 
                </nav> 
              </div> 
            </div> 
          </div> 
          <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row"> 
              <div class="col">
  <signin v-if="sign === signin"></signin>
<signup v-else></signup>

              </div> 
            </div>
           </div>
           </div>

    </div>
    <template id="signup">
        <div>
            <h1>авторизация</h1>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template id="signin">
            <div>
                <h1>регистрация</h1>    
                </div>
            </template>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
      Vue.component('signup', {
          template: '#signup'
        })
        Vue.component('signin', {
          template: '#signin'
        })
const app = new Vue({   
  name: 'app',
    el: '#app',
    data: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sign: 'signin'
    }
  },
    components: {
   signin,
    signup
  },
  methods:{
    switchSign(currentSign){
      this.sign = currentSign;
    }
  }
});
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле у тебя каша. Таких рекомендаций нет в официальном руководстве.
Итак, по порядку.

1. Перечитай [руководство по компонентам](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html). У тебя ошибка в том, что ты зарегистрировал компоненты глобально при помощи `Vue.component(/**/)` и "что-то" пытаешься засунуть в объект `components:{}` корневого инстанса Vue. У тебя **не определены** переменные `signin` и `signup`.
2. По поводу `template` компонентов - перечитай про [обработку крайних случаев (X-Template)](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates). Не нужно вставлять `<template>` компонента в разметку, для этого есть `<script type="text/x-template" id="component"></script>`

Отпиши в комментарий, когда перечитаешь и, если не получится исправить ситуацию, я дополню ответ кодом

Comment: заработало, нужно было просто убрать  components: {
   signin,
    signup
  } , получилось методом тыка)

Comment: Ну тем лучше)))

Comment: еще один буквально вопрос, вот из главного файла <template id="signin"> перенес в другой html файл, и как теперь его скриптом подгружать?

Comment: А зачем? шаблон рендерится в момент запроса этого компонента. Но ты можешь использовать SFC (single file components) `.vue` и использовать их как асинхронные компоненты

Comment: что бы код огромный не был, это сейчас здесь пару строчек, а потом будет регистрация с авторизацией. У меня нет файлов с .vue расширением, только js, html, php, пользуюсь пока что как подключаемой библиотекой

Comment: Тогда никак. Можно только разбить код, если используешь `php` или шаблонизаторы (`smarty`,`blade`,`twig`). Описывашь компоненты в разных файлах и в зависимости от страницы выводишь нужные компоненты. Но с этим скорее запутаешься

Comment: Лучше разберись с `vue_cli` и полноценным процессом разработки с webpack. Там много интересного, но разработка в разы ускоряется с использованием HMR (hot module reload)

Comment: насколько возможно с vue_cli использовать вместе с php?

Comment: это разные технологии. Ты просто делишь свою работу на фронт и бэк. В php пишешь логику обработки данных, но практически не затрагиваешь клиентскую часть. В клиентской части на vue ты пишешь все, что связано с отображением данных, которые предоставляет php, а также логику взаимодействия с пользователем. 
`vue_cli` - это всего лишь  консольная утилита, позволяющая быстро настроить окружение для разработки фронта

Comment: подключая vue как обычную библиотеку делаю клиентские скрипты где делаю запрос axis.get или axis.post(page.php) и получаю результат, вот потому и интересуюсь как оно будет работать при vue_cli